# Prestashop redirects to wrong page after change of address during purchase

Tags: redirect, checkout, prestashop-1.5

I have the following issue on a Prestashop webpage i am working on. When you start a purchase and decide to actualize your address on step 3, you are redirected to the page for changing address however when you save the changes you are redirected to a 404 error for missing page with url `http://www.miplata.es/index.php?controller={$back}?back=index.php` instead of being redirected to the next step of the purchase. I guess that the controller for the redirect might be the problem bug I'm not sure.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to solve it?